# Creating a simple family feud game with two players

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I was doing a simple python game ( I'm new to programming, sorry if asked anything wrong ) where two players play and answer the questions.

**Underlying principles of the game:**

There are several possible answers that a player can guess from. Each possible answer has a certain amount of points associated with it. If the player guesses an answer that exists in the possible answers, they will be rewarded with the corresponding amount of points.

```
question = "Name something James Bond eats everyday" 
possible_answers = [("LEMON/CITRUS", 25), ("KETCHUP/MUSTARD", 25), ("TOOTHPASTE", 19), ("ZIT/BLACKHEAD", 14), ("GLUE", 6), ("MY POOPER", 3), ("LOTION BOTTLE", 2), ("LIQUID SOAP/SHAMPOO", 2)]

# Test case 1
player answer: mustard
25  

# Test case 2
player answer: mayonnaise
0
```

The player can continue guessing until they run out of strikes or they guess all the possible answers.

Each correct guess increases the player's score. The player loses a strike if they guess something that has already been guessed before or guess something that isn't in the set of possible answers.

```
# Test case 1
player answer: cry
player answer: cry some more
player answer: cry a lot
player answer: wake me at 3 am
player score: 39, player strikes left: 0

# Test case 2
player answer: cry
player answer: make mess
player answer: eat my candy
player answer: poo
player answer: fart
player answer: puke on me
player answer: pee
player answer: burp
player answer: nurse
player score: 98, player strikes left: 2
```

**Here are the rules of the game:**

First, we will assume that player 1 always gets the right to try to make the first guess.

If player 1 makes a correct first guess, they get control of the round. Otherwise, player 2 gets control of the round.

The player that has control of the round will keep guessing and collecting points until they guess all the possible answers. In this case, the round is over and the points are banked to the controlling player's account.

If the controlling player loses all their strikes before guessing all the answers, the other player gets a chance to steal the controlling player's points for the round.

If the other player makes a correct guess, all the points earned by the controlling player in the current round are banked to the other player's account.
If the other player makes an incorrect guess, all the points earned by the controlling player in the current round are banked to the controlling player's account.
Then the round ends.
When a player steals the points, they do not gain the points of their guess. They only gain the points that the controlling player collected for the current round.

**Example Case:**

```
question = "Name something a baby does that would be unacceptable in a roommate."
possible_answers = [("CRY/AT 3 A.M.", 39), ("POO/WET SELF", 28), ("PUKE/ON ME", 9), ("BURP", 8), ("MAKE MESS/TOSS FOOD", 5), ("FART", 4), ("PEE IN MY FACE", 3), ("NURSE/ON MY NIPS", 2)]   
# Test case 1 - player 1 controls, gains 84 points, loses all 3 strikes, player 2 gets chance to steal but fails, player 1 wins round 
player 1 answer: cry
player 1 answer: poo
player 1 answer: puke
player 1 answer: burp
player 1 answer: cry
player 1 answer: cry
player 1 answer: cry
player 2 answer: cry
player 1 score: 84, player 1 strikes left: 0,   player 2 score: 0, player 2 strikes left: 3    
# Test case 2 - player 1 controls, gains 84 points, loses all 3 strikes, player 2 gets chance to steal and succeeds, player 2 wins round
```

**Here is what I already did:**

```
question = "Name something a baby does that would be unacceptable in a roommate."
possible_answers = [("CRY/AT 3 A.M.", 39), ("POO/WET SELF", 28), ("PUKE/ON ME", 9), ("BURP", 8), ("MAKE MESS/TOSS FOOD", 5), ("FART", 4), ("PEE IN MY FACE", 3), ("NURSE/ON MY NIPS", 2)]

player_1_strikes_left = 3
player_2_strikes_left = 3
player_1_score = 0
player_2_score = 0

player_score = 0
match = False

player_1_answer = input("1: ")
player_2_answer = "000"

player_1_answer = player_1_answer.upper()
player_2_answer = player_2_answer.upper()

player_1_control = None 

if player_1_answer.upper() != "ooooooooooooooooooooooo":
    for item in possible_answers:
        answer = item[0]
        if player_1_answer in answer:
            player_1_control = True 
            player_1_score += item[1]
            possible_answers.remove(item)
            match = True
            break
        else: 
            cplayer_1_control = False
else:
    None 

#if player_1_control != True 
while player_1_score < 0 :
    while player_1_control == True:
        while player_1_strikes_left != 0 and len(possible_answers) != 0:
        
          player_1_answer = input()
          player_1_answer = player_1_answer.upper()
          match = False
          for item in possible_answers:
              answer = item[0]
              if player_1_answer in answer:
                  player_1_score += item[1]
                  possible_answers.remove(item)
                  match = True
                  break
    
          #print(possible_answers)
          if not match:
              player_1_strikes_left -= 1
              if player_1_strikes_left == 0:
                  player_1_control = False
              else:
                  continue 
              break


    
    while player_1_control == False : 
        while player_2_strikes_left != 0 and len(possible_answers) != 0:
        
          player_2_answer = input()
          player_2_answer = player_2_answer.upper()
          match = False
          for item in possible_answers:
              answer = item[0]
              if player_2_answer in answer:
                  player_2_score += item[1]
                  possible_answers.remove(item)
                  match = True
                  break
    
          #print(possible_answers)
          if not match:
              player_2_strikes_left -= 1
              if player_2_strikes_left == 0:
                  player_1_control = True 
              else:
                  continue 
              break



print(f'player 1 score: {player_1_score}, player 1 strikes left: {player_1_strikes_left},   player 2 score: {player_2_score}, player 2 strikes left: {player_2_strikes_left}')
```

I don't know why but the code runs infinitely and doesn't change the player when the other one runs out of strikes.

Thank you very much beforehand!

Comment: [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69976651/creating-a-simple-family-feud-game-with-4-rounds-and-2-players) has been closed because you were asking too many questions. split your problem into smaller parts, you will often find the answer yourself. if not, ask here but we address only specific questions: they should fit into 10~20 lines of python code

Comment: @diggusbickus addressed and edited to one specific question, thank you